# Slow query selecting 13,000 rows from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I need to select certain rows from a mysql table that has VARCHAR Primary Key index ID.

I therefore use a query (but obviously 13,000 ids instead of 3)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN ('id1928383','id3838339','id38383')
```

For the majority of tables this works well (~0.2s) but for some tables the query takes much longer (~10-11s).

The only thing different about the tables that do not work is they have a larger Data_length? Any ideas how I can speed up the slow query's?

Comment: Are you sure that these `VARCHAR`s are keys on *all* of the tables?  How big of tables are we talking about?

Comment: data_length is 42549248 with 528,567 rows. I have checked the tables in question and the show index statement says that the column has index_type BTREE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to speed up this query:

- **Use `INT` instead of `VARCHAR` for the `ID` column**

Computers in general are much better with numbers than with strings, so this will speed it up considerably.

- **Add the `ID` as an index.**

This will create an ordered table with that indexed column, where the searching and ordering will be a LOT faster.

- **Use PDO**

If you are using this with PHP, I recommend you use PDO, since it has a query caching system, and can significantly improve results if there are many identical queries being run. I suppose other programming languages have similar mechanisms.

- **Upgrade MySQL**

For all the software you use it is recommended to use the latest version for many reasons. If I'm not mistaking, there was a performance issue with `IN` in an older version of MySQL, which was fixed a few version later, but you could be one of the unlucky few that still uses that version.

---

That's about as much as I can help, if you need more help, you will need to post more info (table structure, database structure, programming language, etc).

Comment: Use INT instead of VARCHAR for ids
Will this make much difference? Also I would then have to convert all my row_ids to ints in my program to access the data?

ID is an INDEX

I am using MySQL and R

Comment: Will do some benchmarks, but I can tell you now that the difference will be pretty notable. I know it will be a pain if you decide to do this.

Comment: Ok well Ill have a look into it myself. Although it doesn't explain why some tables are fast (or reasonable) and some are slow (10x).

Comment: You could try to do the following - export that table and import it into your local database, then convert it into INT, and see if it will make a difference.

Comment: Just to update I have now tested this using ints and it is working for the slow tables on my test data. I have to re-do all the database now which will take a couple of days. Why doesn't mysql do this anyway e.g. when indexing set-up a 1 to length of ids counter and have a table to convert between the two. Anyway thanks for the heads up I just presumed mysql would do the work for me with varchar keys.

Comment: Good luck, glad to be able to help

Answer (score 1):

It takes real time to look up 13,000 rows.  For each value, it has to:

1. Process the index to find the record location
2. Load the page into the page cache
3. Return the results

Alternatively, it might be doing a table scan to read each row individually and comparing to the list.  Can you provide the explain for the long running version to determine which method is used.

If looking up the values in the index, my guess is that the large tables do not fit into the page cache.  This results in an additional read-the-page hit for most of the values.

The simplest solution is to increase the size of the page cache.  You might also try putting all the ids into a temporary table and joining that to the larger table.  When doing this, it would be particularly helpful to build an index on the temporary table.

Comment: EXPLAIN says
"1      SIMPLE GSM1051587 range       PRIMARY PRIMARY      32 <NA> 13273 Using where"

How do I change page cache I cannot see it in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all `id` columns are indexed.